# Are the matrix elements of $S$-matrix Lorentz invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams, lorentz-symmetry, perturbation-theory

In quantum field theory, the $S$-matrix is defined as a time-ordered exponential
$$
S=T\Big[\exp\Big(-i\int d^4x \mathcal{H}_{\rm int}\Big)\Big].
$$

Since $\mathcal{H}_{\rm int}$ is a combination of fields grouped in a Lorentz invariant manner and $d^4x$ is Lorentz invariant, does the matrix element $S_{fi}$ between an initial state $i$ and a final state $f$ also Lorentz invariant if the states $i$ and $f$ are normalized as $$\langle \vec{p},s|\vec{p}^\prime,s^\prime\rangle=\frac{(2\pi)^3}{V}\delta_{ss^\prime}\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{p}^\prime)?$$ This is crucial for me to undertsnd because I am using an argument to claim that a Feynman amplitudes are Lorentz invariant starting from a relation which relates the scattering amplitude $S_{fi}$ to the Feynman amplitude $\mathcal{M}_{fi}$.

Comment: For the S-matrix to be Lorentz invariant you would need to show that $\mathcal{H}_{int}$ is Lorentz invariant. Are you provided with any form of the interacting part of the Hamiltonian?

Comment: @fielder $\mathcal{H}_{\rm int}$ is Lorentz invariant because for non-derivative interactions $\mathcal{H}_{\rm int}=-\mathcal{L}_{\rm int}$, and $\mathcal{L}_{\rm int}$ is Lorentz invariant. I have explained this in my question.

Comment: "from a relation which relates them" what does this mean?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Please see the edited line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *whole point* of QFT is that it is a framework that allows you to define Lorentz (co)variant scattering amplitudes. In fact, under some general hypothesis it is the *only* framework with that property. The expression in the OP is not *manifestly* Lorentz covariant, although it turns out to be, after a very cumbersome analysis. See ref.1 for a detailed discussion.

Alternatively, the Lorentz covariance of the scattering amplitudes follows immediately from the Lorentz invariance of transition amplitudes, say, as given by the [LSZ formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula), e.g.
$$
\langle p_{1},\ldots ,p_{n}\ {\mathrm {out}}|q_{1},\ldots ,q_{m}\ {\mathrm {in}}\rangle =\int \prod _{{i=1}}^{{m}}\left\{{\mathrm {d}}^{4}x_{i}{\frac {ie^{{-iq_{i}\cdot x_{i}}}\left(\Box _{{x_{i}}}+m^{2}\right)}{(2\pi )^{{{\frac {3}{2}}}}Z^{{{\frac {1}{2}}}}}}\right\}\prod _{{j=1}}^{{n}}\left\{{\mathrm {d}}^{4}y_{j}{\frac {ie^{{ip_{j}\cdot y_{j}}}\left(\Box _{{y_{j}}}+m^{2}\right)}{(2\pi )^{{{\frac {3}{2}}}}Z^{{{\frac {1}{2}}}}}}\right\}\langle 0|{\mathrm {T}}\varphi (x_{1})\ldots \varphi (x_{m})\varphi (y_{1})\ldots \varphi (y_{n})|0\rangle 
$$
for a scalar field theory in four spacetime dimensions. In turns, the correlation function $\langle 0|{\mathrm {T}}\varphi (x_{1})\ldots \varphi (y_{n})|0\rangle$ is Lorentz invariant, which is manifest when written as a path integral,
$$
\langle 0|{\mathrm {T}}\varphi (x_{1})\ldots  \varphi (y_{n})|0\rangle\sim \int \varphi (x_{1})\ldots \varphi (y_{n})\ e^{-I[\phi]}\ \mathrm d\varphi
$$
where $I$ is the action, a Lorentz scalar.

All the elements in the above formulas are manifestly Lorentz covariant, and so it immediately follows that so are the $S$-matrix elements. The case of arbitrary spin is handled similarly, although the details are more involved. Again, see ref.1 for the explicit construction.

FWIW, the $S$-matrix can also be written directly as a path integral, sidestepping the need of ever introducing the LSZ formula. See e.g. ref.2, where we can read, for example, (p.11)

> Comparing [...] with [...] we can say that to get the $S$-matrix in the momentum representation one is to calculate the Feynman functional integral [...]. This observation shows that the $S$-matrix is defined by means of a functional integral in a more elegant manner than the evolution operator. [...] This is specially attractive in the case of field theory because [it] becomes manifestly Lorentz covariant [...].

**References.**

1. Weinberg - *Quantum theory of fields, Vol.1. Foundations*.
2. Faddeev - *Introduction to Functional Methods*, from *Methods in Field Theory*, edited by North Holland. See also [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/513339/84967).

Comment: Thanks. Even though I have seen it, I am not fully familiar with LSZ formula. But whatever you wrote makes sense to me and answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

1)
A normalization condition for one-particle states $| \vec p \rangle$, which is Lorentz invariant is
$\langle \vec p | \vec q \rangle = 2 E_p (2 \pi)^3 \delta^{(3)} (\vec p - \vec q)$
(The factor $2$ is conventional)

However, if we write
$\delta^{(3)} (\vec k) = \int \frac{d^3x}{(2 \pi)^3} exp (i \vec k \cdot \vec x)$
we can state
$\delta^{(3)} (\vec 0) = \frac{V}{(2 \pi)^3}$
Hence
$\frac{\delta^{(3)} (\vec 0')}{V'} = \frac{\delta^{(3)} (\vec 0)}{V}$

So, the normalization in your post is invariant as well.

2)
The S-matrix element $\langle f|S| i \rangle$ for $n$ asymptotic momentum eigenstates is given by the LSZ (Lehmann-Symanzik-Zimmermann) reduction formula which for scalar quantum fields $\phi (x)$ states
$\langle f|S| i \rangle = [i \int d^4 x_1 exp (-i p_1 x_1) (\Box_1 + m^2)] \cdot \cdot \cdot [i \int d^4 x_n exp (i p_n x_n) (\Box_n + m^2)] \langle \Omega | T \{ \phi (x_1) \cdot \cdot \cdot \phi (x_n)\} | \Omega \rangle$
where $-i$ in the exponent applies to initial states and $+i$ to final states

The LSZ formula is constructed from Lorentz covariant fields, hence the S-matrix element is an invariant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm afraid that it doesn't answer my question. I asked if $S_{fi}$ is Lorentz invariant. You answered whether my normalization is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 I edited my post as point 2) to answer to your question. (I added also a factor $(2 \pi)^3$ at the denominator of the definition of the $\delta$ for a normalization).